Chromedriver and Chrome version error with puython
The current Chrome version is 127.0.6533.120. The Chromedriver version is 127.0.6533.119, which was automatically downloaded with the command:
service = Service(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install()) 
My problem is that when I launch a Python script using Chromedriver, I encounter the following error when it tries to start Chromedriver:

OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application.


I’m not sure how to resolve this issue while waiting for Google to release a new version. Does anyone have a solution for this? Thanks!
I try to find solution with the beta command for Chromedriver, but didn't work, and I'm not sure it's a good solution in the future.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I use python script to automate some navigation with chromium and scrap informations.
I launch Chromium on my script like this:
        service = Service(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
        driver.get("https://XXXXXXXX.com/")

The problem actually is that Chromium isnt launch anymore with the 127.0.6533.119 version. Error is "OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application."
It was working in the past.
